# How to fix data connection between rds database and asp.net application?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, amazon-rds

I am not able to connect to my aws-rds instance from asp.net application

I have been trying to connect my asp.net application with my aws-rds instance i have tried using connection strings setting, its doesn't work, but i am also able to connect to my aws-rds database from sql management studio

i also tried to use migration but when i do update-database from console it create a new database in local db

i have also try to provide all required setting and data and then publish my application with aws toolkit but when opening my site link it gives a error -An error occurred while processing your request.
so any can help me with this issue or provide me the proper steps

[image]

Comment: could this be a firewall config issue? do you need to whitelist your IP(s)?

Comment: @scgough i have already specify to allow all traffic that are allowed by my rds instance

Answer (score 0):

Check Inbound and outbound rules for instance.
try to connect it with your instance IP.

refer [enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html)